# get error in Sign firefox extensions

Tags: firefox, certificate, sign

after downloading firefox sign packages from Mozilla web site. i'm using [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Signing_a_XPI) to SIGN extensions.

after set path i'm trying to use this command:

```
certutil -N -d .
```

to create a test certificate, but i get this error:

```
C:\Firefoxdevelopment>certutil -N -d .
CertUtil: Unknown arg: -N

CertUtil -?              -- Display a verb list (command list
CertUtil -dump -?        -- Display help text for the "dump"
CertUtil -v -?           -- Display all help text for all ver
```

after that i'm try to use below code:

```
signtool -G myTestCert -d . -p"password"
```

i get this alert error dialog

[image: signtool error]

Answer (score 0):

Your path is executing the microsoft version of certutil
C:\Windows\System32\certutil.exe

you need nss and nspr which includes the correct version of certutil and signtool.